# How to handle simple geospatial queries (distances) in ruby with activerecord-postgis-adapter?

Tags: rails-activerecord, postgis

I've got a lot of lat / lon points in a csv file, I've created a table which has a point in the 4326 projection (table postcode, field location)

I'm building data like this:-

```
factory = ::RGeo::Cartesian.preferred_factory(:has_z_coordinate => false)
p  = factory.point(data_hash[:latitude], data_hash[:longitude])
```

and storing p in the location field.

The issue then is that I want to find "near" records to a given point.
I've seen some promising code at:-

https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/blob/master/test/spatial_queries_test.rb

so  I wrote the following:-

```
factory = ::RGeo::Cartesian.preferred_factory(:has_z_coordinate => false)
p  = factory.point(53.7492, 1.6023)
res = Postcode.where(Postcode.arel_table[:location].st_distance(p).lt(1000));

res.each do |single|
  puts single.postcode
end
```

But I'm getting exceptions (unsupported: RGeo::Cartesian::PointImpl)

I assume I'm needing to do some converting or something, any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the factory you use. Try to generate point from a spherical factory:

```
p = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326).point(53.7492, 1.6023)
```

Also check rails logs to see the output query and run it manually in PG. Make sure that the query runs without problems.